# Listen for right mouse button(Context menu) in Ckeditor 5

Tags: ckeditor5

How do I listen for right mouse button(Context menu activation) in Ckeditor 5 when the user click on an element in the editor.

For left mouse button I use ClickObserver which works perfectly, but ClickObserver don't seem to work for the right mouse button

Answer (score 1):

As per [CKEditor migration document](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/migrate.html#configuration-options-compatibility-table), context menu options are removed in CKEditor 5 and official standard is to use [contextualToolbar](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorconfig-EditorConfig.html#member-balloonToolbar).

> CKEditor 5 does not come with a context menu, contextual inline
>   toolbar is preferred instead to offer contextual actions.

**Update:**

I found a hack which you could use, but I wouldn't recomment it so **USE IT AT YOUR OWN RISK!**

```js
function onEditorMouseDown(evt) {
  if (evt.which == 3) {
    alert('You right clicked the editor!');
  }
}

var elem = document.querySelector('#editor1');
var cEditor = ClassicEditor
  .create(elem)
  .then(function(editor) {
    let container = editor.ui.view.editable.element;
    if (container) {
      container.addEventListener('mousedown', onEditorMouseDown);
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.1.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<h1>CKEditor 5 Example</h1>
<textarea id="editor1"></textarea>
```

**Explanation:**

What I'm doing here is finding out editable area within the editor and adding a event listener for mousedown event on the element.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I did not intend to use the ckeditor context menu (We don't use any of the ui part of ckeditor 5). But have the ability to listen to right mouse events really been removed?

Comment: Sorry, I have been occupied by other issues. This looks like it might work, but then I have the issue of finding out exactly which element in the model the user clicked on. But it think I can solve that by getting the dom element the user clicked on, and then using the mapping class to get the view node for that dom elemen. And then getting the model element for that view code.

Comment: Yes, you can use event.target to find out which element was clicked on.